# Leaderboards (temporarily) not working any more

Tags: support, status-norepro, leaderboard

**Edit:** never mind, this seems to have been a temporary glitch - they're working fine now.

Some of my old questions, such as [Paint Starry Night, objectively, in 1kB of code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69930/paint-starry-night-objectively-in-1kb-of-code) or [Write Moby Dick, approximately](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/152856/write-moby-dick-approximately) have large numbers of really great answers and still occasionally get answers today. I used to use the leaderboard snippet to keep track of the scores, but I found today that it's not working any more - no lists of scores come up when I run it.

I didn't find a previous meta post about this. Has something changed that stops the snippet from working, and if so, is there a way it can be fixed?

Comment: SE makes minor API changes occasionally, usually without telling anyone.

Comment: Works for me on Safari and Chrome, breaks on Firefox probably due to personal issues with jQuery and school wifi.

Comment: Both of the leaderboards in those questions work for me (using Chrome), it may be your browser

Comment: If you want to investigate further (it works for me too), try again with the Network tab open in your browser's debugger. That should show if any requests are being blocked or not working right. You might also want to check the console to see if any other errors occured.

Comment: The Paint starry night works fine for me on Firefox.

Comment: Huh, they're working fine for me as well now. I'm on a different network now, so it was either a temporary glitch or a network issue.